# Editing another user's comment deletes it

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, moderator-abilities

When I edit my own comments, all is good. But when I as a moderator edit someone else's comment, the comment is deleted. (Using my powers to edit my own comment outside the five-minute window does not cause a problem.)

I only noticed this today, although Pat Ludwig [said in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/264257#264257) that he thought it had happened to him a couple of days ago. Looks like the revision hasn't changed since the 24th, so that would make sense.

EDIT: Still a problem in rev 2011.1.2.1.

Comment: Comment that any moderator can test it out on. I like turtles!

Comment: Another comment for testing. Turtles all the way down.

Comment: Well, that other one didn't last long

Comment: Somebody's going to need to make me an MSO mod so I can test this. For science

Comment: Looks like all the previous test comments died. [Do they still? (No, they no longer do) -random]

Comment: Checked my email, it happened to me on the 24th.  At the time I assumed it was my fault and didn't take the time to investigate further.  (Was a tad busy :))

Comment: @Pat Always assume the user is at fault. Then blame SOIS. If all else fails, frame other mods

Comment: @Michael - Thanks, lets get that tip added to the moderator's manual!

Comment: Happened to me once as well, a few days ago, I've been too afraid to edit comments ever since :(

Comment: @Michael: [You monster](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tax4e4hBBZc)?

Comment: @RBemrose: No YouTube here. What is it?

Comment: YouTube was to some Portal 2 game trailer.

Comment: @michaelmyers - delete test -- OK

Comment: Test comment!!! OK

Comment: @Oak - no need to worry any more... *Edit by Ivo*

Comment: Yup, I can safely edit @Marc's comment

Comment: @random: Yes, it was... I was referencing the quote at the end of the video.  "I think we can put our differences behind us, for science.  You monster."

Comment: The vanished comment from Austin Myers was getting around not being able to view the YouTube clip in the first place @rbe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was my bug; I fixed it a few days ago. I'll see if I can resurrect those comments...

(they will be resurrected in the next build/deploy cycle)

Comment: This should probably be changed from status-norepo to status-completed then, yes?

Comment: the wheel of blame is a harsh, harsh mistress

Answer (score 1):

I saw this a few days ago as well, but I suspect it might be a temporary bug in the mod dashboard which allows inline editing.

I can't reproduce it now, either by editing the comments above or by editing a flagged comment in the mod dashboard.

Comment: You guys screwed up!  [ha ha](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIrhVo1WA78) - (remove tongue from cheek now)

Comment: It happened to me while editing from the regular question view, not from the dashboard. Was a week or two ago, though.

Comment: @Oak [ha ha](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIrhVo1WA78) !